# Format NSString (Char-Replacement, UTF, ...)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsstring, utf

Google Maps API delivers me a string which contains the German letters: ö, ä , ü and probably several other special characters.

The string looks like:

`@"  (several spaces ...)   Frankfurt an der Oder     (several spaces ...)            "`

(1) If I try `stringByReplacing ...` and make the spaces disappear, it looks like:

`@"FrankfurtanderOder"` ... which is even worse. So I need to delete the spaces before the first and after the last word, not the spaces in between. How to do this?

(2) Sometimes Google delivers me `@"W\U00fcrzburg, Deutschland"`

... there is nothing said in the `JSON`-request about encodings ... could it be that the JSON-parser and not the api is the problem?

However, still I have to solve it. Any ideas?

Thank you so far!

**EDIT:**

For (2) I'll do the workaround and replace some UTF-8 characters ... (Even If this is definitely not the best solution ...)

```
&auml; -> ä
&ouml; -> ö
&uuml; -> ü
&Auml; -> Ä
&Ouml; -> Ö
&Uuml; -> Ü
&szlig; -> ß
&quot; -> "
\u00C4 -> Ä
\u00E4 -> ä
\u00D6 -> Ö
\u00F6 -> ö
\u00DC -> Ü
\u00FC -> ü
\u00DF -> ß
```

Comment: can you provide a link that shows the second problem? I want to test something. And how do you decode the JSON?

Comment: Look for `Google Directions API`. There's a good tutorial on their site. There is nothing to decode. I parse it with `JSON`. Maybe `JSON` messes it up because when I do the request in a browser it displays `ü` correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`– stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet%3a)

```
NSString *str = @"  Frankfurt an der Oder   ";
NSString *trimmed = [str stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
NSLog(@"\"%@\"", str);
NSLog(@"\"%@\"", trimmed);

2012-03-26 14:10:49.302 xx[3752:f803] "  Frankfurt an der Oder   "
2012-03-26 14:10:49.333 xx[3752:f803] "Frankfurt an der Oder"
```

---

about the ü. Does the `\U00fc` appear in an UILabel or did you just got them from a NSLog? In my experience sometimes NSLog doesn't print the decoded letters but they appear okay in interface elements.

Comment: +1 for handling case 1, But that doesn't handle case #2, so -1 for that. End result: no vote.

Comment: I can say that you're right. But in my case, it's wrong for the `UITextField.text` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need a few steps here:

```
NSString *unescapeBackslashes(NSString *input)
{
    // find occurences of '\'
    int index = 0;
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, input.length);
    NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString string];

    while ((range = [input rangeOfString:@"\\u" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(index, input.length - index)]).location != NSNotFound) {
        assert(input.length > range.location + 5);

        char temp[5];
        strncpy(temp, [input cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] + range.location + 2, 4);

        [output appendString:[input substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(index, range.location - index)]];

        // append the unicode char
        [output appendFormat:@"%C", strtol(temp, NULL, 16)];

        index = range.location + 6;
    }

    [output appendString:[input substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(index, input.length - index)]];

    return output;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{ 
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *input = @"    W\\u00fcrzburg, Deutschland    ";
        NSLog(@"Input: %@", input);

        NSString *trimmed = [input stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
        NSString *escaped = unescapeBackslashes(trimmed);

        NSLog(@"Trimmed: %@", trimmed);
        NSLog(@"Escaped: %@", escaped);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong--the string is already appearing in ASCII, i.e. the escape codes are not unescaped to produce the accented letters.

Comment: Trimming the white space works (I used Matthias' method). But your approach delivered `W\u00fcrzburg, Deutschland`, in the `UITextField.text` and in the `NSLog's` as well.

Comment: WTF? `NSLog => Output with ü?! ((    118553     )`

Comment: @Darwin that's a bit interesting, that's not what happens on my machine.

Comment: Okay, that looks a bit complicated to me. Before I do something wrong: How do I have to integrate this? Thank, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Just pass the string you receive from the JSON to the function, and do what you wish with the string returned (I assume you know how to use a C-function).

Comment: @Darwin I don't see that issue, and I compile with ARC. Can you paste the line where the error is / send a screenshot of the error?

Comment: OK, first thing: My fault and solved. Second thing: Mach-O Linker error?!

Comment: OK, first thing solved. But not working anyway ... `Ohne Ü? ==> (
        (
        "W\U00fcrzburg, Deutschland"
    )`